# While using 3G internet connection, Crashlytics gives no internet connection error for event uploading

Tags: ios, xcode, events, crashlytics, google-fabric

I am using Fabric/Crashlytics SDK on my iOS application (version Crashlytics 3.10.7). When I use 3G internet connection (connection exists I tested) and debug the app, I have realized Crashlytics logs on Xcode (10.0) console. Although there is internet, it says there is an error on LocalUploadTask for uploading crashlytics events to the [url](https://e.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/events)  Logs are below in detail:

```
2018-09-26 09:39:07.153257+0300 xxx[9164:1662764] Task <81F06DC0-348D-431F-B209-DE3E666BE2EE>.<129> load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "İnternet bağlantısı çevrimdışı gözüküyor." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, NSUnderlyingError=0x283715590 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1009 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalUploadTask <81F06DC0-348D-431F-B209-DE3E666BE2EE>.<129>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
"LocalUploadTask <81F06DC0-348D-431F-B209-DE3E666BE2EE>.<129>"), NSLocalizedDescription=İnternet bağlantısı çevrimdışı gözüküyor., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://e.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/events, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://e.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/events, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1} [-1009]
```

But when I try it on wifi connection there is no such an error. Is there any problem here today or any bug on this version?

using:

- Xcode 10.0
- App deployment target min 10.0
- Crashlytics 3.10.7
- Answers 1.3.7